# AngularJS add new rows from Database

Tags: angularjs

I have an app which fetches data from a database on load.
Since the data in the database changes every few seconds, I would like to dynamically add the new data in the database into the table in the HTML page.
Any ideas on how to implement without reloading the controller?

The current code:
app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap','countTo']);
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        if(input) {
            start = +start; //parse to int
            return input.slice(start);
        }
        return [];
    }
});
app.config(['$compileProvider', function($compileProvider) {
  $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|http?|file|data):/);
}]);

app.controller('customersCrtl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.$emit('LOAD');
    $scope.progressBar = { progress : 0 };
    $http.get('ajax/getCustomers.php').success(function(data){
        $scope.list = data;
        $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
        $scope.entryLimit = 50; //max no of items to display in a page
        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
        $scope.$emit('UNLOAD');
    });
    (function progress(){
        if($scope.progressBar.progress < 100){
            $timeout(function(){
                $scope.progressBar.progress += 1;
                progress();
            },5);
        }
    })();

    $scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
        $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
    };
    $scope.filter = function() {
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.filteredItems = $scope.filtered.length;
        }, 10);
    };
    $scope.sort_by = function(predicate) {
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };

});

app.controller('delayController',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.$on('LOAD',function(){$scope.loading=true});
    $scope.$on('UNLOAD',function(){$scope.loading=false});
    }]);

app.controller("PostsCtrl", function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.progressBarScanned = { progressScanned : 0 };
(function tick() {
  $http.get('ajax/scanStatus.php').
    then(function(response) {
      $scope.posts = response.data;
      $scope.scanProgerss = $scope.posts[0].isScanning;
      $scope.scanPercentage = $scope.posts[0].scanPercentage;
      $scope.timeToFinish = $scope.posts[0].timeToFinish;
      $scope.amountScanned = $scope.posts[0].amountScanned;
      $scope.totalItemsToScan = $scope.posts[0].totalItemsToScan;
      $scope.avgScanTimePerItem = $scope.posts[0].avgScanTimePerItem;
    });
    $timeout(tick, 1000);
})();
(function progressScanned(scanned){
        if($scope.scanPercentage < 100){
            $timeout(function(){
                $scope.progressScanned.progress = 1;
                progressScanned();
            },5);
        }
    })();
});


//Modal
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal) {
    $scope.open = function (imageKey) {
    $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        backdrop: true,
        windowClass: 'full',
        controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, data, imageKey) {
            $scope.data='';
            $scope.data = data;

            $scope.getImage = function () {
                return $scope.data[imageKey];
            }

            $scope.cancel = function () {
                $modalInstance.dismiss('close');
            };
        },
        resolve: {
            data: function() {
                // access outer controller scope by using $scope.$parent
                return $scope.$parent.data;
            },
            imageKey: function() {
                return imageKey;
            }
        }
    });
}};
```

Comment: call your $http.get in a method using $timeout or $interval

Comment: wouldn't this will reload the entire table?

Comment: Well if you can handle server side to return only new data then with timeout or interval u can push that new data in already fetched, so first time fetch all and every 5 sec only new data...but better way is using websockets but then you need to change logic

Comment: @necross - it would, but I didn't read your code to see what logic you were using to retrieve the data. I was really answering the question about how to avoid reloading the controller. Any solution will require you to filter the data in some way.

Comment: Thanks Lee. Im using php and MySQL to return a JSON array. What I am trying to achieve is inserting new records from the MySQL database without reloading the entire table which in some cases contains thousands of records.